# How to do automated remote operations on servers using .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I need help in building a windows application to run some commands on remote servers. These are some of the operations I'll need.

1. Copy and paste,
2. Edit file contents and
3. Set scheduled tasks.

I've only done web applications till now and remote access with code is new to me. It would be preferable to have all the components in the local machine. Is it possible this way. Ive seen some samples online but none of them gave me a good starting point to get a grasp on the subject.

EDIT:
For anyone that is interested, I found a solution to this by using WMI (windows management instrumentation). With I'm able to access a remote server and run dos commands. The below example from code project helped a lot.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/server-management/Intro2WMI4.aspx#
You can also try impersonating and using normal file and directory operations, but I had trouble cause it seems to not work unless the accounts on the remote and local system are similar.

Comment: You could write an ASMX Web Service (SOAP) and consume this Web Service from within your Windows application.

Comment: You could build a simple web application that takes coded http requests for each operation and then performs them on your server.

Comment: For future readers: if you were to write a web service, then ASMX should not be used. WCF should be used instead for any new development.

Comment: Its a production server and I'm not supposed to add anything new to it. This rules out PsExec as it leaves a service running on the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PsExec: http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb897553